# How do I check if stopwords are enabled on a full-text indexed table?

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-2012

I know how to enable them on my full text indexed table, but I don't know how to check if they are already enabled using an SQL command.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Enabling them ... Do you mean by changing the source code?

Comment: `ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON SomeTable SET STOPLIST = OFF` to turn off. But I need to query to see if it's on or off.

Comment: Sorry , confused for Mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the fulltext-properties of a table can be queried by using the [sys.fulltext_indexes dmv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186903.aspx). In this case, stoplist_id should have the information you are looking for.

Comment: To add to this:  sys.fulltext_indexes isn't very useful on its own, this connects it to more human friendly information:

`select name, * from sys.fulltext_indexes as fullTextIndexes
left join sys.objects as objects on objects.object_id = fullTextIndexes.object_id`

Answer (score 0):

you could try inserting a document containing only stop words, and then query it (pseudoquery: id=xxx AND text contains "the") - if you get a result, stopwords are being indexed (no stoplist).  Hacky, but it will work.